# Flutter ScreenUtil().setSp(22) doesn't work after null safety upgrade to 5.0.0+2

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

We have used flutter_screenutil package in our flutter project. In current version of our application, this is how we set the fontsize, and it works fine.

```
fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(22)
```

After upgrading this package to 5.0.0+2, suddenly fontsize changed way too small. Upon debugging, we found that ScreenUtil().setSp(22) returns 4.5. That's what it does.

The way we used to initialize ScreenUtil in old version:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.init(context, allowFontScaling: false);
```

The way we initialize now after upgrading the package:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
          designSize: Size(1080, 1920),
          builder: () => Scaffold(...
```

Is there anything wrong or are we missing anything here? How can we get the fontsize back to normal?

Comment: Have you submit a bug report into their GitHub?

Comment: I did. Their response was to update Size width and height in ScreenUtilInit. But that doesn't work. I don't want to recalculate all the label sizes. So, I'm waiting for response on github issue.

Comment: then that's the way you need to continue your claim/bug. StackOverFlow is not a source to create bug or expect fixed from libraries. Only the source code with a bug report is the way to do it.